# Why primary key is always considered as a constraint not a just property in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Property may be more specific, as it applies some constraints on its member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primary key is a property of a table, but it constrains the values that you can put in the table. Specifically:

- None of the columns that comprise the primary key can be null

  - Within the set of rows in the table, no two can have the same value for the primary key